# angular material datepicker is passing one date lesser than what the user has selected

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use Angular material latest datepicker in my application. I am using it for filter input so I have start and end range. selected value goes right till service but, in the network,in the payload, it shows one date less then what the user has selected.

Suppose if the user has selected 12/1/2017 to 12/31/2017, it is showing correct date just before I am making request to the server
[image]

but in the request payload, It is selecting one lesser date.
[image]

Comment: i suppose the datepicker shows your local time. but to the server it sends UTC :)

Comment: that's weird and funny at the same time :)